# EKS and ECS Pricing confusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

I have one confusion, did we need to pay for ECS separately, if i had already EKS cluster with t3.medium EC2 instance as worker node. Because in documentation i found that there is no addition charge for ECS if we have EC2 instance.

Comment: Your question is confusing because it mentions both EKS and ECS, which are two completely separate services. Are you using ECS or EKS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service) and ECS (Elastic Container Service) are two distinct services on AWS. Both are used for container orchestration. EKS, as the name suggests, is a managed Kubernetes cluster whereas ECS is an AWS-native solution.

Both EKS and ECS can be used on top of either EC2 instances or on Fargate. Fargate is a “serverless” solution in the sense that it manages the underlying servers and the autoscaling for you.

If you run ECS on EC2 instances instead of Fargate, you will only pay for the EC2 instances, just like normal. There is [no additional cost](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/pricing/) for the fact that you run an ECS cluster on top of them. EKS however does charge you for the cluster itself, regardless of the underlying launch type.